# Finding the global optimum for a non-linear problem in excel using solver or elsewhere?

Tags: excel, optimization, solver

I've created a specific model on excel which uses historical returns of firms and aims to find the optimal point between the return and a stop-loss point. Basically I need the optimal stop-loss %. I've been using excel's solver, however, it only finds the local optimum. Can solver somehow find the global optimal point or even a few optimal points? If not, are there any programs that can be recommended to use?

P.S. I am not extremely good at mathematics, and transporting all of the information from excel to an equation or something is probably not an option.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You can either upgrade for the commercial solver which has better support to find a global optimum

Comment: For clarity on what you have...  Are you saying that from data you have created some kind of formulaic model (moving average, ARIMA, regression, or whatever) and you want to find global minima over the output (range) of the function looking forward?  And in the prediction window of interest there are several minima?  There are solvers that can do this, but need a bit of clarity.  A bit confused as you say "move all the information from excel to an equation".  If you have a model, you have an equation, right?  That is what the solver would be chewing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either upgrade for the commercial solver which has better support to find a global optimum. Alternatively, you can write a macro that will initialize the various variables to random values and repeatedly launch the optimizer and checking within each loop if a better solution has been found and store the value of the variables before continuing the search.

See https://www.solver.com/upgrade-excel-solver
Note: I am not affiliated with this company. I would rather have you use open source solutions. This is possible with some training.